# Update of scikit-learn fails with Anaconda

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda

I'm using Anaconda. When I do `conda list` it shows me that currently scikit-learn 0.19.1 is installed. I would like to upgrade to 0.19.2, so I'm doing

```
conda config --append channels conda-forge
conda install scikit-learn=0.19.2
```

But then I'm getting the following error:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current cha
nnels:

  - scikit-learn=0.19.2

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
```

How can I install scikit-learn 0.19.2?

Comment: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/scikit-learn Only for linux and mac user. I guess you are using Windows.

Comment: Yes, I'm using windows. How can I get it for windows?

Comment: I have now tried pip install -U scikit-learn and it installed 0.19.2. So when I do conda list I now see both 0.19.2 and 0.19.1 but it is somehow not recognized by pyCharm. When I go into the pyCharm settings 0.19.1 is listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scikit-learn==0.19.2` You're missing a second `=` sign, so it's not finding the package

```
$ pip install scikit-learn=0.19.1
Invalid requirement: 'scikit-learn=0.19.1'
= is not a valid operator. Did you mean == ?
```

Comment: Same error with == but I think the problem is that it is not available for windows.